# jquery find the value in an array and delete it

Tags: jquery, arrays, find, push

I have an array

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

what I want to do is check for a value say 3 and then remove it

```
[0,1,2,4,5]
```

I was trying to check for it using

```
jQuery.inArray(questions[count], $(this).index())
```

but was getting quite erratic answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) too

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
var removeItem = 3;

array = array.filter(function(value) {
   return value != removeItem;
});
```

### [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/u820u8zr/)

Comment: all good answers, this is the one I like  best, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` may work for this task:

```
 var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
 var removeItem = 3;

 array = jQuery.grep(array, function(value) {
    return value != removeItem;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.splice`:

```
array.splice($.inArray(3,array),1);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j52wm6dz/)**

Answer (score 0):

Know to use of `.indexOf` in javascript

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
var removevalue  = 3;
arr.splice(arr.indexOf(removevalue), 1);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u820u8zr/1/)